# while loop showing only first result

Tags: php, mysql

```
    <div class="row">
<?php 

require 'config.php';
$query = "SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 8";
$do = mysqli_query($con, $query) ;
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($do)){
$query="SELECT * FROM `lang` where id='$result[langid]'";
$do=mysqli_query($con,$query);
$lang=mysqli_fetch_array($do);
$query="SELECT * FROM `users` where id='$result[userid]'";
$do=mysqli_query($con,$query);
$user=mysqli_fetch_array($do);
$String=$result['titel'];
$text_length = 30; // طول الحروف المراد ظهورها
if (strlen($String) > $text_length) {
// اذا كان طول النص اكبر من النص المراد ظهورة نفذ التالي
$String = substr($String, 0, 33);
// قص من النص التالي ما بعد الرقم في المتغير الخاص بطول الحروف المراد ظهورها
$String .= " ...";
// اضف إلى النص بعد ارجاعه هذه النقاط
}
?>
<div class="col-md-3" >
<div class="panel  panel-default ">
<!-- Default panel contents -->
<div class="panel-heading" >


<?php 


echo $String;
?>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><b>&nbsp;<?php echo $user['username']; ?></b> </p>
<p> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span><a href="posts?lang=<?php echo $lang['id']; ?>"><b>&nbsp;<?php echo $lang['name']; ?></b></a></p>
</div>
<a href="show<?php echo $result['id']; ?>"><div class="panel-footer text-center ">
<b>عرض التحدي</b>
</div></a>
</div>
</div>
<?php   } ?>
</div>
```

Hi this is the code it's only showing the first result in while loop I want 8 results.
I have 3 tables from MySQL and 3 querys I tried every thing I could but nothing changed.

Any help?

It's PHP 5.4 and mysqli class

```
Update: now the code works

<div class="row">
<?php 

require 'config.php';
$query = "SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 8";
$do = mysqli_query($con, $query) ;
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($do)){

$query="SELECT * FROM `lang` where id='$result[langid]'";
$do1=mysqli_query($con,$query);

$query="SELECT * FROM `users` where id='$result[userid]'";
$do2=mysqli_query($con,$query);

$String=$result['titel'];
$text_length = 30; // طول الحروف المراد ظهورها
if (strlen($String) > $text_length) {
// اذا كان طول النص اكبر من النص المراد ظهورة نفذ التالي
$String = substr($String, 0, 33);
// قص من النص التالي ما بعد الرقم في المتغير الخاص بطول الحروف المراد ظهورها
$String .= " ...";
// اضف إلى النص بعد ارجاعه هذه النقاط
}
?>
<div class="col-md-3" >
<div class="panel  panel-default ">
<!-- Default panel contents -->
<div class="panel-heading" >


<?php 

while ( $user=mysqli_fetch_assoc($do2) AND    $lang=mysqli_fetch_assoc($do1) ){
echo $String;
?>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><b>&nbsp;<?php echo $user['username']; ?></b> </p>
<p> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span><a href="posts?lang=<?php echo $lang['id']; ?>"><b>&nbsp;<?php echo $lang['name']; ?></b></a></p>
</div>
<a href="show<?php echo $result['id']; ?>"><div class="panel-footer text-center ">
<b>عرض التحدي</b>
</div></a>
</div>
</div>
<?php   }} ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing several queries, but looping only on the last one which is `SELECT * FROM 'users' where id='$result[userid]'`, and it sounds like this query is going to give you a single result. (A single user)

You can either store the results of each queries, and use them all in a single loop later on, or join your tables to get all the data you want from a single query.

Comment: even if i but it inside one loop it's the same

Comment: now the code works after adding second while for the $lang and $user